# Syntax on if statement

Tags: python

1.when i run the code i get else: print("no checkpoint found")
2.IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
3.i have tried to fix it but i could not

```
  def Score(self):
                  return sum(self.reward_window)/(len(self.reward_window)+1.) 

            def Save(self): 
                torch.save({'state_dict' : self.model.state_dict(),
                            'optimizer' : self.optimizer.state_dict,
                            },'last_brain.pth')  

            def Load(self) :  
                if os.path.isfile('last_brain.pth') :  # this is where i get the syntax error

                    print("=> Loading last brain...") 
                    lastbrain = torch.load('last_brain.pth')  
                    self.model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])  
                    self.optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer']) 
                    print ("done") 
                else: print("no checkpoint found")
```

Comment: `else:` needs to be at the same indentation as `if`.

Comment: Please post your code as a code block, not image. Also, please include the full `stacktrace` of your error.

Comment: @PacketLoss Syntax errors don't have stack traces.

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as your code, and not as images. See: [mcve], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO[1], I think the other cause of the issue is that the other functions are defined in the same code block as `self`. I’d recommend formatting similar to:

```
def score(self):
  # code for score...
  # etc...

def save( self ):
  # code for save
  # etc...

def load(self):
  # code for load...
  # etc...
```

1: I do not use Python regularly enough to know all the legality’s in terms of function declarations, but in most languages, as far as I am aware of, you cannot have multiple function declarations in what the language sets as a code block ( braces in C/C++/Java, Indents/Colons in Python ). If anyone know of exceptions or the proper legalities for Python feel free to set me straight in the comments)

Comment: You can declare functions inside functions in Python; and in the OP's code, the functions are not inside the function because they are less indented than the function's body (which is a single return statement). There is an indentation error because they are more indented than the first function's `def` statement, but not indented far enough to still be part of the function's block. The cause of a syntax error is not a matter of opinion, so it's a bit strange to say "IMO" about this.

Comment: In Python, `def` is an executable statement and *can* appear inside a code block. You can use an `if` test to define a function two different ways. This is a normal approach when writing code that has to handle different versions of an API.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not properly indented. It should be like this

```
def Score(self):
            return sum(self.reward_window)/(len(self.reward_window)+1.) 

def Save(self): 
            torch.save({'state_dict' : self.model.state_dict(),
                        'optimizer' : self.optimizer.state_dict,
                        },'last_brain.pth')  

def Load(self) :  
            if os.path.isfile('last_brain.pth') :

                print("=> Loading last brain...") 
                lastbrain = torch.load('last_brain.pth')  
                self.model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])  
                self.optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer']) 
                print ("done") 
            else: print("no checkpoint found")
```

According to your indentation, you were defining `Save()` and `Load()` inside `Score()`, which is not allowed in Python. Hope this resolves your issue.